# "Fuzzy" Display Problems on New OpenSUSE 11.3 Install

Tags: linux, display, opensuse

I have a old Desktop that has a new installation of OpenSUSE 11.3 on it.

To get straight to the point, whenever I try to start-up OpenSUSE, my display goes "fuzzy" (almost like a badly tuned TV) and **sometimes** (not always) my monitor goes black and says "Out of Range: 15.6kHz/49Hz":

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

I assumed that this was a driver problem, so I download the drivers from nvidia and ran the shell script, completed and rebooted. Then OpenSUSE failed to boot with something like "nscd failed to start". At that point I decided to re-install and I did, but this time I tried un-checking "Automatic Configuration" to see if that helped. Got through the install and still have a problem.

Unfortunately, my Linux troubleshooting skills are non-existent, so has anyone got any ideas on what could be the problem (is it the display driver?) and how I can fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I did another re-install and then followed the instructions from http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_the_hard_way